# How to have dynamic .env files instead of hard coded localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have 2 `.env` files (one for Vue and one for Laravel). Both of them have `localhost` hard coded inside of them. That means that I can't access my application from another computer on my network. It would be nice if it was dynamic *(except for production)*

For example if I go to my other PC and access my site at `http://192.168.1.100:47344` then it won't work because it is hardcoded to localhost *(escpecially frontend calls)*.

But I can't write javascript or PHP inside the `.env` files to change `localhost` to something like `window.location.host` and for PHP `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`. I can't find the solultion.

My Vue `.env`:

```
VITE_SERVER_URL=http://localhost:41166
VITE_APP_ENV=dev
```

And my Laravel `.env`:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:47344
APP_URL=http://localhost:41166
```

Comment: If you mean that you want to access your server from other computers, you could use 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost. This means the server will listen on all network interfaces, not only the virtual loopback network interface (aka localhost), but also the real network interface that connects you to the lan.

Comment: @BoukeVersteegh You mean to put 0.0.0.0 in javascript?

Comment: You could give your dev server a fake domain name (e.g., http://mylocalserver.com) then use the hosts file on each device to redirect the traffic accordingly (localhost on the server / IP on the external device).

Comment: @matticustard Yes, I could give it a domain name but that means every user will need to set up their hosts file. Not ideal.

Comment: Another not ideal and a very dirty workaround is to temporarily change localhost to something like `192.168.1.100` - but that's far from perfect.

Comment: @Liga: 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost, in the .env files.

Comment: Also if you need different configurations for dev and production, you would usually solve that by having multiple .env files, e.g. `.env.production`. How the correct .env files are chosen depends on the application (e.g. vue or laravel), and if i recall laravel might not support multiple env files and requires you to always name it .env (not sure)

Answer (score 0):

Even if your app url is set to `localhost`, the application is still accessible, as long as there is no firewall restricting it. You can also access it through `127.0.0.1` or the local IP address assigned to your machine.

---

The way to get your local ip address depends on your system, but you can just run this in the `node` console

```js
const { networkInterfaces } = require("os");
const nets = networkInterfaces();

for (const name of Object.keys(nets)) {
  for (const net of nets[name]) {
    if (net.family === "IPv4" && !net.internal) {
      console.log({name , address: net.address});
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note that if you're running this in docker the setting may need to be `0.0.0.0` because 127.0.0.1 is a loopback host.